# Signal R # Adding User Group at Initialize Level?

Tags: signalr, azure-signalr

Hello all how we can add user group when we are establish the connection.

I m using https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@microsoft/signalr@3.1.8/dist/browser/signalr.min.js Library

I m initializing connection with below code #

```
let hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(hubUrl)
.configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
.build();
```

now what I need as any Client try to create connection with my Hub with above code it will be going to be part
of one my group I don't want to after Initialization?
so at initialize level or opening connection  I want group to be assigned to Client.
any though

Comment: Group management is handled on the server side. See https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-7.0 for information about groups.

Comment: I want to initialize group at the time of creating connection not with some event

Comment: public async override Task OnConnected() we may need to do code